# Text mining on sentences with the tm.package in R

Tags: r, text, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, tm

I'm working with the tm package in R. 
I have several txt.files in a folder and a list of 30 sentences.

Now I have to check if my files contains these sentences.

How can I create now a programming which considers sentences and not single words?

Comment: Do the sentences need to be exact matches? You might be better off using regular expressions, as that isn't really what `tm` is designed for.

Comment: yes, exactly. It's pretty sure, that these sentences are available in the most files because they are like names. Oliver, do you have an idea?

Comment: There are a few approaches you could take, you will need to write something that can loop through multiple files and perform the check. One idea could be to read in each file using `readLines`, split the sentences out using `strsplit` according to some sort of regular expression, create a vector containing the sentences you want to match against, and then return a boolean value for each file like `any(source_sentences %in% target_sentences)`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a potential approach.  Also you may want to look into the `readtext` package for quickly reading in an entire directory of files as text in one function call.

```
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)

sample_text <- "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.  Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.  But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate—we can not consecrate—we can not hallow—this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us—that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion—that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain—that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom—and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth."

# this must be lower-case because tidytext will tokenize to lower-case by default
sentence_to_match <- "we are met on a great battle-field of that war."

sentences_df <- tibble(text = sample_text) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>% 
  mutate(sentence_match = str_detect(sentence, sentence_to_match))
```